# Resource hints in HTTP header not detected in Lighthouse

Tags: meta-tags, lighthouse

I have resource hints in the document head that are detected by the browser and in Lighthouse. However, if I move them to the http header (so they can be read by the browser without parsing the document) then they are ignored, at least by Lighthouse.

Here is an abbreviated version of the http header link:

`link: <https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/>; rel=preconnect, <https://fonts.googleapis.com/>; rel=preconnect; crossorigin, </local/path/font.woff2>; rel=preload; as=font; crossorigin, <https://www.facebook.com/>; rel="dns_prefetch"`

If I put this in the document like this then it all works wonderfully with the fonts downloading first:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="/local/path/font.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
<link rel="dns_prefetch" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
```

It is just the fonts that I am concerned with now, however. I have tried with extra quotes around the attributes in the header but no joy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had not included `type` in the http header version for font.

I also added quotes around the values.

This worked:

`link: <https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/>; rel="preconnect", <https://fonts.googleapis.com/>; rel="preconnect"; crossorigin, </local/path/font.woff2>; rel="preload"; as="font"; type="font/woff2"; crossorigin, <https://www.facebook.com/>; rel="dns_prefetch"`